# What order are hats displayed on the leader board?

Tags: support, winter-bash-2012

In what order are the hats displayed on the right side of the Winter Bash [leaderboard](http://winterba.sh/leaderboard)?

It obviously isn't random as you can see from the image below, several hats are always placed before/after others. **But what exactly is the ordering?**

[image: leader board]

Comment: "It obviously isn't random as you can see from the image below, several hats are always placed before/after others." ...and why can't that be just a coincidence?

Comment: @Yannis It isn't. The head phones are always placed before the black hat for example. Look through the entire leader board ;)

Comment: Hmm.. I always thought it's the order they were received..

Comment: In the screenshot, the position of Cheddarhead and the red cap (Gotta Catch 'em All) is swapped for Manishearth compared to the first 2, so it appears there isn't an fixed order.

Comment: @ShawnChin No, it isn't?

Comment: @AustinHenley well... you got me wondering..

Comment: @PhaDaPhunk I HAVEN'T SLEPT! Not knowing has kept me awake all night.

Comment: @AustinHenley think I might have something

Comment: @austin Ooops. Mistook the yellow hard hat as cheese. My bad.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The difficulty of the hats challenge:
The hats are in a difficulty order chosen by the programmers. Rare and hard to get hats (like secret hats) always seem to come up first. And hats of the same categories always come in the order `+30`, `+15`, `+5`. Also it seems that getting upvoted on many questions / answers is harder than getting many upvotes on a single question / answer because they always come up first. And the logic is good. It shows your "best" hats so far.

The difficulty order so far:

- I Do Say So
- Brundhilde
- Witticism
- Yakety Stacks
- Bushido
- Gotta Catch em All
- Moshi Moshi
- Yer a Wizard
- Shiver Me Timbers
- Spoiler Alert
- La Margritte
- Git R Done
- Jammin Out
- Soup de Jour
- Cat on the Hat
- Constantinopolitan
- My Dear Watson
- Cheddar Head
- Just Jesting
- Howdy Pardner
- Copacabana
- Where is He!?
- Cake is Not a Lie
- The Abby
- Gangnam Style
- A Need for Speed
- Guide my sleigh
- n00b hat
- I Feel Fine
- L'chaim

Comment: Check out my updated answer. Since someone said my ordering was incorrect (they could just be mistaken) then it could mean its based on the hats you have unlocked.

Comment: We did give hats a hard/medium/easy ranking internally, which was likely turned into a quantifiable (and thus sortable) metric on the back-end of the design.

Comment: There you go problem solved

Comment: Edited for correction on Bushido.

Comment: @Aarthi Post an "official" answer so I can accept! :)

Comment: @AustinHenley Is there something missing in my answer for it to be accepted ?

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:** Not all of the leader boards have the same ordering. But it is consistent for a particular leader board. **There is an order.**

Unsure of the reasoning behind the order but here is what I have figured out (may be some out of order near the top but I can't tell based on the leader board at the moment) from left to right on the leader board listing:

- I Do Say So
- Brundhilde
- Witticism
- Yakety Stacks
- Bushido
- Gotta Catch em All
- Moshi Moshi
- Yer a Wizard
- Shiver Me Timbers
- Spoiler Alert
- La Margritte
- Git R Done
- Jammin Out
- Soup de Jour
- Cat on the Hat
- Constantinopolitan
- My Dear Watson
- Cheddar Head
- Just Jesting
- Howdy Pardner
- Copacabana
- Where is He!?
- Cake is Not a Lie
- The Abby
- Gangnam Style
- A Need for Speed
- Guide my sleigh
- n00b hat
- I Feel Fine
- L'chaim

Comment: The order's not like that at all for me.

Comment: @irrelephant I'd be interested in seeing a screen shot. You are sure you are looking at the MSO leader board?

Comment: What about bushido ?

Comment: @PhaDaPhunk It is in my list. But at the time only one person that I could see had this and I know it is above La Margritte.

Comment: @AustinHenley He is mistaking. I look at is order and it fits perfectly with this.Except for the fact that you forgot And `I Feel Fine` which is posting on a specific date. Which is as easy as L'chaim. Which is pretty much the Difficulty order I was talking about. You just made the list tought I should add it

Comment: I added your list to my answer and added a few mores in the right order.