# The mysterious Epic Punyon Beard

Tags: discussion, winter-bash-2012, secret-hats

I have just seen the hat known as [**Epic Punyon Beard**](http://winterba.sh/epic-punyon-beard) for the first time. Does anyone have any information (or hints if you don't want to spoil it) on this mysterious hat!?!?

Here are the given (but not so useful) clues:

[image: hat short description]
[image: hat description]

The hat in action:

[image: anna with a beard]

**UPDATE:** Shog9 states that the beard is possible but *very* difficult to obtain. **However** based on [What order are hats displayed on the leader board?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/159531/169404), Aarthi said that they have an internal difficulty that they are ordered by and yet the beard is not placed anywhere near first. **This does not add up.**

**UPDATE 2:** The beard is not located in [sprite-128.png](http://cdn.prom.sstatic.net/WinterBash/img/sprite-128.png) or [sprite-32.png](http://cdn.prom.sstatic.net/WinterBash/img/sprite-32.png)
[image: all hats?]

**UPDATE 3:** FYI, the user [dmck](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/192625/dmck) has the beard.

Comment: I thought maybe it was for visiting [Jason Punyon's profile](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/6212/jason-punyon) but I haven't gotten it. :(

Comment: I notice only mods seem to have it?

Comment: Perhaps [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2012_phenomenon) has some hints (ctrl+f aquarius).

Comment: Jason Punyon: the new Kevin Bacon.

Comment: Seems like it only exists on Meta.

Comment: @irrelephant Maybe but not sure. Meta users have been the first to unlock most of the hats so far.

Comment: In response to update 2: nope, it's not in the sprite. It's here: http://cdn.prom.sstatic.net/WinterBash/img/2096626522-128.png.

Comment: See comments in http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/159229/152962

Comment: RE Update 2: None of the secret hats are in the sprite sheet.

Comment: *None* of the secret hats are listed in the sprite, they all have their own separate image. Otherwise we'd be able to guess too easily, now won't we?

Comment: @Mac: meet [Katey HW](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/167684/katey-hw?tab=summary). Not a mod, no questions, no answers, last (and only) activity: a comment on March 27.

Comment: @ЯegDwight Notice that she works at *Stack HQ*...

Comment: @ЯegDwight - please have a look at my answer. Those are actual quotes that I found around. If the hat is not manually awarded (only dmck and katey-hw have it outside of mods, and Katey seem related to the HQ) then I am pretty sure it has something to do with that site. It referes to the age of aquarios AND Jason. So try to log at some strange hour on that site - midnight.... or 8:08 (time ad which Jason baby was born, it seems). Anyway, it reminds me of the level 17 in the first Diablo

Comment: The fact that it isn't in the regular spritelist makes me think that it's something to do being manually awarded. I oughta go waste my time and brute force the remaining hats

Comment: technically, [anyone](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/company/stack-exchange) can get this.

Comment: @jcolebrand: All the other seekrit hats have their own separate image and aren't in the spritelist.

Comment: @Jin Can anyone *still* get this?

Comment: @ЯegDwight: indeed. At the time, only mods had the "hat". Since then, some non-mods have managed to get it, such as [dmck](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/159782/the-mysterious-epic-punyon-beard#comment462850_159808).

Comment: @Jin - assuming the beard is staff only (as your answer implies) and dmck was an exception... the comment about that easter egg on the winter bash page is true? Refering to this - [link](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/159186/are-there-any-secret-hats/159191#comment461740_159191) . Or it was only a joke?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Yeah, I don't know what you're talking about with this beard...

Comment: Hmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmm

Comment: Seems it is NOT the konami code. Unless I tried it on the wrong page. Still waiting for something to appear on that site. Maybe an unicorn flying in the snow?

Comment: It doesn't seem to fly - it just stands there, smugly

Comment: Hey! Congratulations!

Comment: Before I get distracted again by that hat. Congrats for the new born. ^_^

Comment: Congratulations! It is truly a joyous occasion!

Comment: @RoryAlsop. ^_^' ... I should have said "an unicorn flying, drawn by the snow" ghgh

Answer (score 43):

After spending too much time looking into this riddle I still don't know how to get the hat.

But it looks like a tribute to Jason Punyon, a Stack Exchange developer on the Careers 2.0 team. I'm guessing he was growing his hair [until a very special event](https://twitter.com/JasonPunyon/status/281933313730547712).

Here is a before photo of Jason:

https://twitter.com/i/#!/JasonPunyon/media/slideshow?url=pic.twitter.com%2FlV3hcdEQ

And here is an after:

https://twitter.com/i/#!/JasonPunyon/media/slideshow?url=pic.twitter.com%2FYUwfzbuP

Congrats Jason!

Comment: He looks like one of the classic computer scientist.

Comment: Thanks dmck <fifteen>

Comment: You might see a special something somewhere...

Comment: @JasonPunyon Thank you!!

Comment: One might actually end up ripping out their hair out of frustration while figuring out this riddle. In unrelated news, I'm due for a haircut today, or entry into the Shaggy look alike contest.

Comment: @JasonPunyon Congrats!

Comment: @JasonPunyon,  congrats with the little human. And try to enjoy every moment, they grow up real quick losing cuteness each year... ;-).

Comment: We have a time then! Now the question is: How can I see the time local time from the winter bash site?

Comment: @JasonPunyon I'm going to be blunt about this: can I have a beard? Please? Pretty please?

Answer (score 26):

Searching for that hat may prove... frustrating, so:

Does everyone know that Jason Punyon had an adorable baby?

[image: babby!]
That's not really an answer to the question, but it's tangentially related to why the hat exists.  Plus, she's cute.

Comment: dmck [beat you to it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/159808/155160), but +1 for babby photo.
 :)

Comment: she's cute, and wearing a hat (!) ... but no beard??

Comment: How adorable! :3

Comment: Now, she is a cute wee thing! Congrats @Jason

Answer (score 24):

I certainly don't see any beards.

You should check your eyeballs for hair.

Answer (score 18):

Looking at the users that already have this hairy extention, I see two groups:

- Moderators and SE people
- Other users

There are a lot of beards on the first group, and I have seen only one in the later group. And he has concratulated  Jason Punyon with his recent offspring in a post. I assume the first group was able to congratulate using other means of communication.

The comments:

- Thanks dmck  – Jason Punyon♦
- You might see a special something somewhere... – Jason Punyon♦

seem to support this view.

People have congratulated him in a comment but that does not triggered a beard. Maybe is it the first time that counts, but without experiment we never know so in order to test this theory:

Congrats Jason!

I can tell you that it changes your life in a way you can't imagine before.

Comment: And I'd like to congratulate *you* for offering the most cynical congratulations I've ever seen. ;)

Comment: Cynical? Kids do change your life.

Answer (score 17):

Beard - what beard? I don't know what you're talking about with this beard...

Answer (score 16):

Beard - what beard?  I'm not sure what you're talking about...

Answer (score 8):

My guess: The developers of the Winter Bash assigned it to themselves. It is probably not awardable to regular users or user moderators.

**Edit:**

[Relevant? Who Knows?](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hair_%28musical%29)

Comment: There is a way to earn this hat - it's just really really difficult.

Comment: @GeoffDalgas Like as difficult as being elected to be a mod?

Comment: Ok, not quite *that* difficult.

Comment: Ok well now I need to find this hat!

Comment: @Shog9 May I please have the beard, pretty please? :)

Comment: Perhaps more relevant would be: `When the moon is in the seventh house / and jupiter aligns with mars / The peace will guide the planets / and love will steer the stars`

Comment: @irrelephant I thought to so too ... "but Astrologist Neil Spencer denounced the lyrics as "astrological gibberish" via http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Age_of_Aquarius

Comment: @irrelephant, I thought so too, and I actually looked further into the details than that wikipedia article. It seems that the only time in december that the moon was in the seventh house was around the 8th -- which doesn't seem to be related to anything. Also, not sure how to check mars/jupiter alignments, but it wouldn't surprise me if there isn't a related one right now either.

Comment: @BenLee Hmm, looking back, it probably has nothing to do with anything in this answer + comments.

Answer (score 5):

It's not just for mods, because I'm a moderator and I don't have a beard. I'm not sure if foxes can grow beards though.

But maybe if I shave off all my fur...brb.

The fur shaving thing doesn't seem to work. Perhaps if we avert an apocalypse?

Or maybe pictures of cute children?

[image: "Ellis and Finnegan"]

Comment: Maybe MSO moderators? SE employees?

Comment: @irrelephant - it's SE employees for the most (if not exclusive) part.

Comment: Phew, I was wondering if I was left out, after seeings so many "the mods have this beard" answers.

Comment: I can't believe I haven't gotten an ounce of love for my cute children.

Comment: +1 for the picture then :-)

Comment: @KitFox: Those the foxlets? Cute :)

Answer (score 5):

My guess is that it is to celebrate bearded little ones.

http://www.secretlair.com/babieswithbeards/

[image]

Actually... I think it is a really creative congratulations to Jason. Congrats!

Answer (score 4):

This is not a hat you are looking for. *handwave*

Comment: Shouldn't that be: "This is not the hat you are looking for?"

Answer (score 4):

The three theories are:

- You must have had something to do with the beardy Jason in the past. This should be fake, since it was him to follow my problems with the Careers site (which reminds me that I could use the vacation to fill that profile — never had time).
- You must go to see the Hobbit movie, all while dressed like a dwarf. Probably you also need a mod to come with you to certify that, or I would already have it.
- That site hides something. Jin said there is an easter egg, and then we have "You might see a special something somewhere". Look at the site and search for a star in the sky. At a precise time. Also remember that "It is not a hat you are looking for".

There is one last theory. Beards will just grow overnight. As someone said "Beard — what beard? I don't know what you're talking about with this beard."

Answer (score 3):

It seems that most diamond moderators have this hat on Meta. Many, but not all, are wearing it.

- https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/3/jarrod-dixon has it but isn't wearing it
- It's not just SE employees, because Jeff Atwood has it.

Some don't (I think community-elected moderators):
-  https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/50049/tiny-tim-post is a moderator, but apparently *doesn't* have the hat.
-  https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/137537/boltclocks-a-unicorn

[Jon Skeet does not have this hat](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet), either here or on SO main.

Comment: Jeff is... special.

Comment: [random](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/9314/random) does not have the beard either.

Comment: There are [diamonds](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/about) and then there are [diamonds](http://stackexchange.com/about/team).  I don't think the first set has this "hat".

Comment: @JonEricson Indeed, some diamonds are just ... *diamondier* than others.

Comment: Naw, I doubt they'd make an employee only badge. Clearly, we're just not moderating ***hard enough***.

Comment: @TinyTimPost how to get this beard hat .... i want this too

Comment: @TinyTim I think maybe we need to suspend a certain number of users...

Comment: @KitFox That's what I thought until dmck got it.

Comment: If Jon Skeet doesn't have it, I'm still not convinced it exists.  The beards on everyone on this page... it's a typo.

Answer (score 3):

Kinda like we all forward the mail to keep msn and facebook free, I'm congratulating Jason [just in case](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/159864/1782).

That was my official congratulation to Jason.

Consider yourself congratulated.