# Hats data in Stack Exchange Data Explorer

Tags: discussion, data-explorer, data-dump, winter-bash-2012

Will the next data dump into the [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/data-explorer/info) contain anything related to hats?

I'm trying to find any clues I can about the [The mysterious Epic Punyon Beard](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/159782/the-mysterious-epic-punyon-beard).

I don't see anything hat related in this [schema dump](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta/revision/89530/105516/).

Comment: A top notch research team (myself, and all of my other personalities) is currently working on the problem. Everything is under control. We expect to have a working vaccine for this pandemic Punyon breakout shortly.

Comment: @TinyTimPost Glad everything is under control...

Comment: @TinyTimPost What does that even mean. Stop answering riddles with a riddle!

Comment: i want beard too...how to get this?

Comment: @TinyTimPost that's what they *always* say before something that, afterwards, is referred to simply as: "the event"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, there won't be any hat data in the data explorer.

Far as the beard goes... the data e̴͉̖̺̞ͥ̽ͧ̎ͩx̤͙̫ͭ̑̿p̅̔̈҉͇̫̤͉̫ĺ̜̗̖̉͐ͨ͗ͦ͟ǫ̱̱̹̹͇͍̫ͫ͂̃ͨ́r̸̻̱̦ͥ̌ͦ̀é̄̇҉̰̥r͍͓̺͙̞̻͍̾̀͊ͯ̈͜ ͇̭̤ͨͯ͌ͭ͂̓̽̇͂͜ would n̶̢̯̜̻ͪ̔̐̓ͣ͋͜o̢̦͕͚͚̳̹̓͞t̯̻̹͖̳̪̭͖ͦͤͯ̈ͧ̂͛͠ ̑͋ͮ̿̒ͯ҉̩̫̟̻̙̰͕͢ḧ̯̝̟̅ͬ́ͩe̴͚̗͓̟͇͓ͫ̐ͪͯ̚ͅͅl͂ͨ̏̓̅ͯͮͯ̌҉̪͎p̔ͨ͏͎͔͉̫̭̙ͅ... oh god...m͈̘̄̍ͭ̇͞a̲̠̣̱̘̘̟͚͖̚͡k͍͉͚̼̣̪̞͙ͥ͜e̛ͣͦ̕҉̣̬̭͇͔ͅ ̫͇̙͉̟́ͤͩͣ̈ͣ́t̢͆̏҉̭̰h̴͚̣̻̪̮̙͎̲͈̃̀̆ͦͨ̃̉̀e̤͍͇ͤ̈́͋̏̂͡͞ ̝̱͖̹̦̪̰͖̐͑ͭ̃ͦ̔̐ḇ̡̢̄ê̜̥̗̼͖̼ͣ̋̆̀̚ḁ̻͚͙̻̭͙ͣ͌͘ṙ̤̟̪ͭ̓̓̋d͉̜̩̯̪̜͔̘ͧͬͥ ͩ̀̓̑̋̅ͣ҉̘̙̭͎̠̖̀s͕͓͐̋̎̍͐̕͞t͍̋̊͛ͤo͎̘ͨ̌ͧ̓̎̔ͣp̎̓̃̔̊҉͙̪̲͎.͇͇͙̲̫̣̻̃͆͋͒̏ͪ̀͠͝ͅ ̡̘̻̜͎̜̖̯̑̄ͧ͡m͎͊̾͑̎̈a̶̸̪͓͇͖̭̬̘̾ͮk̠̜͛ͮ̃ė̷̪̬̠̤̈̇͛̽̅ͪͥ͞ ̒̃͆̿҉̬̣̤í̪͉̇̿͗̏̓̚t̢͔̖̪͇ͥͦ̄̑͌̍ͤ͛͘ ̩ͤͥ̃̀ͨ̈̌̕͢â͇̖̪̗̌͠͡ľ̶̘͉̱̌̊̿l̏̇ͤ̋̎ͬ͗ͧ̎҉̶̩̼̗̹͇͕ ̘͓̮͇̖̻̼͑̄̌͊̉̏̌s̷̝̣͖̞͍͉̈́͑͐̾̑ͅt̷̷͓̯̙ͥ͊ͯo̷̧̥̘͔̻̭ͨ̕p̡̲̫̪̯̹̹͚̦̬̆̀͋̀̅̍͗̀̍.̢̥͇͛ͫ͑͞..