# What is Nicholas Cage doing in Winter Bash?

Tags: support, winter-bash-2012

I snoop around and looked at the CSS & the sprite image being used in the [Winter Bash](http://winterba.sh/) and found out there are quite a lot of hidden hats there.

Do you guys know what those other hats are and what the requirements are needed?

[image: The sprite image with all the hats]

Comment: I waited a long time for Nicolas Cage to appear in the title of SO question!

Comment: he is protecting hat form two troll ...out there

Comment: Found another one, Cake Is Not A Lie - improve a post http://cdn.prom.sstatic.net/WinterBash/img/1900909705-32.png

Answer (score 10):

These aren't hidden hats. The hidden hats have their own images, like this one:

[enter link description here http://cdn.prom.sstatic.net/WinterBash/img/1529797420-128.png](http://cdn.prom.sstatic.net/WinterBash/img/1529797420-128.png)

(Bushido)

Those are just there to troll folks looking for hidden hats. Hence the troll icons. Cage is also trolling you, like he always does:

[image]

Comment: Nice one Manishearth! How many more hidden hats are there? Anyone knows of a wiki page setup somewhere they collected all of these badges/hats?

Comment: @fedmich: I think I have all but [the Epic Punyon](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/159782/the-mysterious-epic-punyon-beard). Click the snowflake on my profile to find these hats. (I've circled them [here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/duYoj.png)). As for figuring out how to get a hat, if you can find the image URL of the hat, it's easy after that.