# What is this doing in the hat sprite-80 image?

Tags: discussion, winter-bash-2013

I found this in the `sprite-80` image with all the hat images in it:

[image: weird thing]

This is not a hat. What is it?

Comment: Looks like a feature that did not make it to release.

Comment: Inquiring minds want to know.

Comment: Or disco, maybe?

Comment: It looks evil, don't let it out

Comment: Looks like a pixelated Shog's head.

Comment: Fun fact: even the [sites fav icons sprites](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/content/img/favicons-sprite32.png?v=51104f54268a2fc18bb7189b8de1378d) contains such a thing: http://i.stack.imgur.com/6WlYL.png ;)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is just something random thrown into the middle of the sprite image to throw off (or troll) people who are trying to find secret hats in there.

[They did the same thing last year.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160069/what-is-nicholas-cage-doing-in-winter-bash)

Comment: Oh. I thought Nick Cage had been replaced by the Autobot sign this year. My bad.

Comment: [Here's the inspiration for the hat](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/tvshowbiz/article-2470094/Kanye-West-rips-leather-trousers-gig-Yeezus-Tour.html).