# Year 3941 in Careers time frame drop down

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

The date selection for *time frames* has quite an unrealistic scope to it. I doubt the year 3941 was intended as a starting point for the drop down!

> [image: Date Selection for Time Frame]

Comment: You could see knights going to careers.

Comment: This is a bug and currently under investigation.

Comment: this bug is planned to be fixed in mid-January 3941

Comment: bug fix in about 6 bi-centuries.

Comment: It all depends on the calendar.

Comment: I'm going to take a leaf from the Mayan conspiracy chaps and assert that the world will end in 3941.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This bugfix brought to you by [Elle's](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/159813/6212) nap.

Should be a bit more reasonable now.