# The secret behind the Epic Punyon Beard

Tags: discussion, winter-bash-2012, secret-hats

I know, the Winterbash has ended (it makes me cry everyday) and still asking questions about it is futile.

However, I was really fascinated by the mystery surrounding [the mysterious Epic Punyon Beard](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/159782/the-mysterious-epic-punyon-beard). As far as I know, this was the only hat for which the requirements weren't made public.

Now that the party has ended, could someone reveal what were those secret requirements? Or is it a secret to die with?

I suspect you'd need to be awarded the hat by a moderator but I like to hope you could gain it via a strange unlikely succession of actions...

Please help me sleep at night again! :)

Comment: dmck answered it in that question...

Comment: @animuson He doesn't actually tell you how to get the hat.

Comment: @Asad: The challenge was congratulating Punyon about the new baby. He got the beard for doing that. What more is there to explain?

Comment: @animuson Gamecat actually tested that. No hat :(

Comment: @Asad: It was only given to dmck. It's not really a challenge anymore once everyone knows you just have to say "congrats"... Everyone would have a beard... dmck worked hard researching that stuff and earned that beard.

Comment: @animuson So you're saying it was impossible to get the beard after dmck's answer?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It was employee-only. The only exception was dmck who got it as a reward for being the first to [figure out](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/159808/115866) what it was all about. That's all.

Comment: Just curious... was it intended as a riddle in the first place? :)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Not really. Well, we know you guys, so we expected nothing less :) But it was really just a nod to Jason and his family.