# Hats order guide (Spoilers)

Tags: discussion, winter-bash-2013

Last year, it seemed to me that hats were ordered (in the leaderboard) by the effort it took to get them (the rarity of the hat).

[I managed to *guess* the order last year](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/159684/174490).

How are hats displayed in the leaderboard this year? If it is still by difficulty, can someone list the order below?

E.g.: The R-E-S-P-E-C-T is always before The Stallman but The Stallman is always before the 3 hats.

[image]

Comment: [Bow tie](http://media.npr.org/assets/img/2013/01/18/Aretha%20Franklin_vert-bff1eb404171763b948df84e06f481cdab0b396c-s6-c30.jpg), [Jesus](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/3d/Richard_Stallman_at_Pittsburgh_University.jpg)

Comment: Speaking of Rarity, I hear there's an MLP hat which I ***MUST GET***...

Comment: Yes, but where do I *order* these hats?!

Comment: @TravisJ In the answer.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

### SPOILERS BELOW

### **Feel free to edit**.

- Oh the Horror
   [image]
- Mr. Binx 
   [image]
- Eureka 
   [image]
- Before It Was Cool 
   [image]
- The Milliner 
   [image]
- The Question 
   [image]
- I See Your Point 
   [image]
- I'm not listening 
   [image]
- Marauder 
   [image]
- Robocop 
   [image]
- Full House 
   [image]
- IG-88 
   [image]
- Sock Puppet 
   [image]
- Make It Rain 
   [image]
- Archaeologist 
   [image]
- Ghost of Winterbash Past 
   [image]
- Bounty Hunter 
   [image]
- Conspiracy Theorist 
   [image]
- R-E-S-P-E-C-T 
   [image]
- Winter Is Coming 
   [image]
- Peanut Gallery 
   [image]
- Chatty Chatty 
   [image]
- The Stallman 
   [image]
- Boater 
   [image]
- Upboated 
   [image]
- Reanimated 
   [image]
- Mr Peanut Monopoly McDuck 
   [image]
- Defender of the Realm 
   [image]
- Florence Nightingale 
   [image]
- Johnny Three-hats 
   [image]
- Link to the Past 
   [image]
- Hello, World! 
  [image]
- Do the Swim 
   [image]
- UpDo 
   [image]
- Chuck Yeager 
   [image]
- Frosty the Snowman 
   [image]
- Passed Judgement 
   [image]
- Hi Ho Silver 
   [image]
- With Great Power 
   [image]
- L'chaim 
   [image]
- Old Hat 
   [image]

This is a first draft of my guesses.

I haven't placed:

- [image]
- [image]
- "First!" 
   [image]
- [image]
- Ho Ho Ho 
   [image]
- Lonesome Cowboy 
   [image]
- [image]
- [image]

Because I don't see a pattern yet.

Also please note that some of the highest hats are placed there randomly but on top because I haven't seen a hat that comes before them yet.

Comment: Different size because I took some from the spritesheet and some from the leaderboard directly. If someone who be kind enough to find the other spritesheet I could change that.

Comment: [Higher resolution hats](http://cdn-prom.sstatic.net/WinterBash2013/img/sprite-128.png?2)

Comment: @MadaraUchiha Thats where I got them. But take a look at the bigger ones there not on the sprite sheet and this is why I suspect a second sprite sheet.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha Actually they are secret hats so I suppose I won,t find them on any sheet.

Comment: Just saw an IG-88 secret hat.  http://stackoverflow.com/users/73681/cobbal

Comment: It is unclear how the With Great Power hat is ordered.  On the overall leaderboard, it is at least after the Past Judgment hat.  But on the SO leaderboard, it is before the Florence Nightengale hat.  Something's amiss here...  I assume that we'll go by the overall leaderboard, so I'll put the hat back in its proper place until we can (perhaps) get clarification.

Comment: @MattDavis On the site leaderboards, hats are ordered by how rare they are on the particular site; on the network-wide leaderboard, it's by how rare they are network-wide.

Comment: How do I get "I see your point"?

Comment: Th doge hat isn't a hat, last year they had arbitrary meme photos in the sprites image too

Comment: @Mr.PeanutMonopolyMcManish Maybe it's a secret, secret hat :P

Comment: I have "old hat" granted for being a member in the first month of SO. I have no idea if / where that might rank. :-(

Comment: @scunliffe Its on the list :) !

Comment: WHAT IS THAT RAINBOW DASH HEAD DOING THERE I WANT IT. They did it! They listed to me! The hat exist!!!!!!!    (see [here](http://meta.sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/952/5173))

Comment: Much hat. Such sekrit. Very doge. Wow.

Comment: @balpha, the position of all the hats appears to be changing on the leaderboard.  I just want to be clear.  A hat's relative position is based on how rare it is, so the more times a hat is received, the less rare it is and the further "down the chain" it moves?

Comment: @MattDavis Yes, that's correct.

Comment: @balpha - no hope of turning that Rainbow Dash hat in an actual hat like in my post above, right ;_; ?

Comment: @SPArchaeologist That's clearly Twilight Sparkle.  Rainbow Dash is blue.

Comment: @KevinPanko URGH. Got the names inverted. My error. And I WAS thinking of Twilight.

Comment: @KevinPanko - not offended if I delete my error right?

Comment: @SPArchaeologist I won't tell anybody!