# How many secret hats are there for WinterBash 2013?

Tags: discussion, winter-bash-2013, secret-hats

I am not asking for spoilers, but how many secret hats are there for WinterBash 2013?

Could we post a list of names *(or would that be too spoiler-y)*?

Comment: 42. Definitely 42.

Comment: The number of secret hats is equal to 1 more than you find.

Comment: Secret hats are by definition, well, secret

Comment: @AmericanLuke - No kidding.  My original question was simply asking for a number.  That doesn't take away from their secret-ness.

Comment: @CodeMaverick Actually.. it does.

Comment: @insertcleverxmasname - So having a number gives you information that leads you to know what they are?  I don't think so.

Comment: I don't want to start a comment war over this but I think it does. The secret is not only about what they are. It is about how you get them, when you get them, how many there are and then what they are. The whole thing is a secret. I personally think revealing part of the information is making it less interesting.

Comment: @insertcleverxmasname - I'm sorry, I just disagree that knowing the number of hats makes it less interesting.  That's just me.

Comment: If you know how many there are you know you can stop looking and or trying to get more of them once you hit that magic number.

Comment: ^^^ that's my point

Comment: [There are 41 total hats](http://cdn-prom.sstatic.net/WinterBash2013/img/sprite-128.png?2).  Plus one super secret hat.

Comment: @KevinPanko There are more than that. Look at my post a lot of them aren't in the sprite sheet.

Comment: @insertcleverxmasname Those are the super secret hats!  (It's also possible that an image in the sprite sheet is not used by the system, so there could be fewer than we expect to see.)

Comment: [It's a secret.](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O8DXE5Sx5m8‎)

Comment: ^^^ ok that was funny!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We'll let you know how many secret hats there were, and what the triggers for earning them were, in our wrap-up blog post when the event is over. :)

Answer (score 5):

The only thing we know is that they exists.

> And it’s possible that there just might be a couple of secret ones, too. (By “it’s possible,” we mean  ”there definitely are, because we made them, like with computer code and everything, so there’s not really much doubt whatsoever.”)

It is a secret so the only way we'll know that is by looking at the post-event blogs if the developers decide to tell us (Hope they do).

I the meantime, you can check [My Hat Order Guide](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/211851/hats-order-guide-spoilers) where I took a look at the hats spritesheet and studied the leaderboards in order to see as many hats as possible.

Comment: Well I know it's secret, but was just wondering if anyone could at least give us a number of how many.

Comment: @CodeMaverick Everything about them is meant to stay secret. No one meta has more information unless they are involved with the project. If they would have wanted to give that information, it would have been in the post about winterbash. Unfortunately I don't think we'll get more information until it's all over.

Comment: I figured as much ...