# How many secret hats are there for Winter Bash 2018?

Tags: discussion, winter-bash, secret-hats, winter-bash-2018

Found this discussion [How many secret hats are there for WinterBash 2013?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/212396/how-many-secret-hats-are-there-for-winterbash-2013) from 2013 which @TimPost revealed the secret number was **42**.

How many secret hats are there for Winter Bash 2018 and do we have a list of the triggers for the secret hats?

Comment: Here's the list: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/319840/395288

Comment: If you're referring to the comment, that was a joke. It's a reference to Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy, not the actual number of hats from that year. We don't reveal the number of hats each year.

Comment: @animuson [I beg to differ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271566/can-we-get-some-hints-for-the-2015-secret-hats). (I didn't dig in other years, but this proves SE team does sometimes reveal the numbers and even give hints.)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

That's not revealed; there will be a blog post at the end of the Winter Bash that would sum up all the hats.

But if the past is of any indication:

- 2012: 8
- 2013: 10
- 2014: 8
- 2015: 13
- 2016: 13
- 2017: 10
- 2018: *at least 9*